# RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() doesn't return -1 even if no child is Checked

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I have a `RadioGroup` radioGroup with 2 `RadioButton` rb1 and rb2.

User checks 1 of them, **say rb1**, at some point of time. Now based on some condition, I want to clean the `RadioGroup` i.e.all it's children should be unchecked.

I'm doing so by `rb1.setChecked(false);` and `rb2.setChecked(false);`.

After this when I call `radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();`, I'm expecting **-1** as return value, but what I get is the *id of rb1*, which I had checked earlier.

Am I doing something wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `radioGroup.clearCheck()`

See the doc : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#clearCheck()